# Three identical SMTP server configurations, one succeeds, two fail in Mail

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, ssl

I have three e-mail accounts each with a different domain name, however all of them send e-mail via the same domain name via SMTP (but each has its own login credentials). To clarify, it looks something like this:

```
user@domain1.tld    imap:mail.domain1.tld    smtp:mail.domain1.tld
user@domain2.tld    imap:mail.domain2.tld    smtp:mail.domain1.tld
user@domain3.tld    imap:mail.domain3.tld    smtp:mail.domain1.tld
```

Each account uses its own e-mail address and password to login via both IMAP and SMTP. This means that I have three SMTP servers listed in Mail, one for each account, and each logging in with the appropriate user-name and password.

However, while one of these works flawlessly, the other two refuse to connect, with no specific error given. If I go into the SMTP server list, neither has a password listed, entering one and saving will cause it to become online then immediately offline, with the password field once again empty.

If I verify the details manually using `openssl` on a command line, then I can confirm that the details are in fact correctly, and that the SMTP server (postfix) is happy to accept requests from `user@domain2.tld` and `user@domain3.tld` even though they're connecting via `mail.domain1.tld`.

Is this a bug specific to Mail? Does it have something to do with the shared domain?

Of course I can just use one common SMTP server, however it seems as though I shouldn't need to. While I'm not sure if it's relevant, the server uses client authentication (by specifying a unique TLS certificate for each user); fortunately it isn't using this for passwordless logins, otherwise a common SMTP server wouldn't work, but perhaps it's related to why Mail is failing to handle this properly?

Comment: Your list shows the smtp server as mail.domain1.tld for all three but later say "Of course I can just use one common SMTP server," which implies the servers shipload differ. This is inconsistent

Comment: Ah, what I mean is that since the SMTP server doesn't restrict the address(es) that I can place in the From header, I can simply have all three accounts using the same set of SMTP server settings (e.g- those of domain1.tld). The problem is that I shouldn't have to do this, especially since I may wish to be restrictive in future, so each account should be able to use its own login credentials for SMTP.